# Процесс авторизации и background

Tags: objective-c, ios

Ситуация : пользователь логинится к серверу, в это время приложение входит в background (звонок, нажатие на кнопку home). Что нужно сделать с этим процессом? Прервать, продолжить? Какие есть варианты еще? Кто сталкивался , помогите. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

После нажатия кнопки `home` Ваше приложение имеет право жить  10 секунд, если за эти 10 секунд приложение авторизуется то все хорошо, что чаще всего. до этих 10 секунд вызывается метод: `applicationDidEnterBackground` у `AppDeelgate`. В этом методе желательно сохранить текущее состояние приложения. мы там сохраняем сессию если же она есть. После выхода из сна вызывается метод `applicationWillResignActive` (да их там кучка вызывается) после мы дергаем класс сессии из базы и из него понятно, была ли начата авторизация если нет то окно логина, если да то где сессия, если есть сессия проверяем ее на валидность запросом, если нету закидываем запрос на авторизацию заного. Как то так.

Comment: > после нажатия кнопки home Ваше приложение имеет право жить 10 секунд, если за эти 10 секунд приложение авторизуется то все хорошо, что чаще всего. до этих 10 секунд вызывается метод: applicationDidEnterBackground у AppDeelgate.

@Bimawa, можно, пожалуйста, ссылочку на что-нибудь официальное про эти самые 10 секунд?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html

Your app delegate’s applicationDidEnterBackground: method has approximately 5 seconds to finish any tasks and return.

Comment: Даже не 10 а 5, на самом деле этот таймер зависит от вида регистрации приложения VOIP и MusicPlayer могут вообще работать в фоне.